# Book header - Chapter name in even an odd pages

Tags: header-footer

I am using the book class for my document. The current version displays the title of the chapter in even pages and the subsection name in odd pages. I want to display the chapter name and number in even and odd pages. What do I have to change in the code below:

```
\renewcommand*\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ \color{title}#1}{}}
\renewcommand*\sectionmark[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ \color{title}#1}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se! Please extend your code fragment to complete small document which we can test as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ \textcolor{red}{#1}}{\thechapter.\ \textcolor{red}{#1}}} 
\renewcommand*\sectionmark[1]{}
```

[image: a]

Try this code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}% dummy text
\usepackage{xcolor}

%****************************** added <<<<<<<<
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ \textcolor{red}{#1}}{\thechapter.\ \textcolor{red}{#1}}} 
\renewcommand*\sectionmark[1]{} 
%******************************

\begin{document}

    \chapter{ONE}
        \kant[1-4]
    
    \section{First sec}
        \kant[1-4]
    
    \section{Second sec}
        \kant[1-4]
        
    \chapter*{TWO}
    \markboth{\textcolor{red}{TWO}}{\textcolor{red}{TWO}} % add the marks
    
        \kant[1-4]
        
        \section{First sec}
        \kant[1-4]
        
        \section{Second sec}
        \kant[1-4]

\end{document}
```

Unnumbered (starred) sectional units do not update the marks (in the book class) but you can add them the manually.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is the answer! This are the changes I did to the two lines of code I have:
`\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ \color{title}{#1}}{\thechapter.\ \color{title}{#1}}} 


\renewcommand*\sectionmark[1]{}`